# ViewData to get data from SQL database does not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewdata

I am trying to get data from database but it gives me NULL data. Due to that I am unable to use ViewData in my aspx file. Am I missing something ?

```
  StudentData data = new StudentData();

            using (var connection = DatabaseConnectivity.GetBranchConnection())
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandText = DatabaseConnectivity.GetIsolationLevelStatement(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted) +
                    @"SELECT" +
                        @"branch_name AS [BranchName]," +
                        @"customerID AS [CustomerID]," +
                        @"firstname AS [FirstName]," +
                        @"lastname AS [LastName]," +
                        @"Grades AS [Grades]" +
                    @"from branchdata";

                connection.Open();
                    ViewData["BranchName"] = data.BranchName;
                    ViewData["CustomerID"] = data.CustomerID;
                    ViewData["FirstName"] = data.FirstName;
                    ViewData["LastName"] = data.LastName;
                    ViewData["Grades"] = data.Grades;
}
            return View("StudentDetails", data);
```

Comment: Capture the query using SQL Profiler and run it manually, to verify that the output is what you expect. Note that the result will be available in `@ViewData`, not in the `data` you pass as a model.

Comment: No it should return with data stored in db.

Comment: @DavidHedlund based on the query I ran in SQL yes it gives me data. And so you mean instead of `data.BranchName` I should do is `@ViewData.BranchName`?

Comment: You have opened a connnection but not executed it or read the data that it returns. All your `ViewData["BranchName"] = data.BranchName;` code is doing is reading the value of your newly initialized `StudentData` object which will have default values. And in anycase you do not assign the values to `ViewData` - you assign the values to the properties of `data` and return the model to the view.

Comment: Oh ya I need to execute the statement. Thanks didn't realize that I have missed that. Appreciate that.